# Is there any official holiday-themed content for D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, content-identification

Obviously, the various fantasy settings may have their own, special holidays, for example in the Forgotten Realms, there are five annual holidays falling between the months, like Midwinter oder Midsummer, and a quadriennal holiday in Shieldmeet.

But for holding a Thanksgiving- or Christmas-Themed session, has Wizards of the Coast ever published a Thanksgiving or Christmas theme adventure? It does not have to be a physical book. Digital content, for example from charity events, would be OK too.

With holiday-themed I mean one that uses multiple trappings, figures or traditions of the real world holiday so it will capture the holiday's feel and allow the players to get that it is a homage to the holiday, without me having to tell them. Using Christmas for example, those [that are typically associated with christmas](https://www.google.com/search?q=things%20related%20to%20christmas), like decorated coniferous trees, reindeer, a D&D version of Santa Claus, singing carols, gingerbread or gift-giving. It does not need to use and for piety reason probably should not use the Christian god, saints or the birth of Jesus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although Faerun does not have Christmas, [Winter's Splendor](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/260142/DDAL0005-Winters-Splendor-5e) is a holiday-themed adventure. The opening scene is a [Midwinter](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Midwinter) Gala, at Cassalanter Villa. It is available to download free from [wizards.com](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/dragon/23/DRA23_WintersSplendor.pdf). It was featured in Dragon magazine, but the [link](http://www.dragonmag.com/5.0/#!/article/116595/103672943) is no longer available.

Comment: Beyond taking place in winter, can you explain what makes this adventure Christmas themed? I read through it and can’t find anything beyond them calling it a holiday themed adventure. What makes this Christmas related?

Comment: I mean on the 16th December this was released as a holiday themed adventure. They are never going to say Christmas because it doesn't exist in DND and because they don't want to be accused of not respecting other holidays, but it is pretty clearly a Christmas adventure and doesn't need Santa to make it such.